# Do pygmy hedgehog pee weird?

Tags: health, urination, hedgehog

I just witnessed my male hedgehog pee and I'm equal parts confused and worried. He hid himself behind the running disk and next to a litter box. I moved the disk away to make more walking space, unaware what he was doing. He then began rocking/thrusting back and forth vigorously and soon after I heard a wet sound, like smacking lips. I realized that moment he must be doing his business and waited for him to finish, then when I've noticed no poo I touched the wood and it was wet. I didn't measure the time but it must have lasted at least a minute.

Is it normal for hedgehogs to pee this way? He used to use sanitary pads and I've seen him pee before on them, he would just freeze for few seconds second and walk away. None of this rocking back and forth or loud splashing.

Comment: Just in case if anyone was wandering why did I touch it - few months ago I was fighting a foul smell that I couldn't get rid of in any way and was suspecting that pee might be the reason. Eventually I had to install an active ventilation system to keep the terarrium from smelling. I had to make sure he did what I thought he did to validate my suspicions. I wasn't sure it was it, because like I said, I usually see him using a pad.

Comment: I don't know much about hedgehogs, so this isn't a full answer. It sounds like UTIs are very common in hedgehogs though, so that's the first thing I would check for. His movements could indicate distress and pain. Maybe you can try to contain him to a pee pad and check his urination habits and how the urine looks. If it continues, I would recommend taking him to the vet. This article seems fairly comprehensive: https://africanpygmyhedgehogs.com/2021/05/18/hedgehog-pee-guide-peeing-on-you-color-issues-and-advice/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He might be doing something different... male pygmy hedgehogs are known to pleasure themselves regularly. The rocking / thrusting you saw could be exactly that. [This excellent book by Kimberly Halzen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16JLN18RB6uQyy6RgtUFK78-p-FwXIFDx/view) even has a short chapter about it on page 42.

Nevertheless, you should pay attention to his peeing habits. Hedgehogs don't mark their territory, so peeing in inappropriate places can be a sign of some medical problem. If you notice him peeing much more often or much less often than usual, you should get him checked by a vet.

If a cat suddenly starts peeing outside the litter box, it's often a sign for an UTI or urinary stones that make peeing very painful. The cat mentally connects the pain to the litter box and tries to avoid it. A pet hedgehog could react the same way to an UTI.

Comment: Oh God... yes, that was definitely what he was doing. And he was doing this since a very long time, assuming he did that every time he was "hiding" from me and freezing when I approached him in his enclosure. Well, urine or not, it still smells and soaks into the wood, so I need to do something about it before the PC fan I mounted on his wall becomes not enough. I already booked a visit with a vet so I'll take it from here, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: One more thing I'd like to ask - is there a simple way to tell whether he is peeing or pleasuring himself? I need to observe him closer now to make sure if he is always using the litter box to pee or not.

Comment: @ReverentLapwing I honestly don't know. At this point the best option is probably to have the vet check his blood or urine for any problem.

Comment: ew. very gross. but that's nature for ya.

Comment: @ReverentLapwing you could collect the liquid (whatever it may be -shudder-) and have it tested to see if it is urine or... *ahem.*